Installing Mechanica on Windows
On Windows I want to executes this code from the Mechanica documentation release 0.0.14:
import mechanica as m
import numpy as np
# potential cutoff distance
cutoff = 1
# dimensions of universe
dim=[10., 10., 10.]
# new simulator, don't load any example
m.Simulator(example="", dim=dim)
# create a potential representing a 12-6 Lennard-Jones potential
(continues on next page)
10 Chapter 3. Quickstart
Mechanica Documentation, Release 0.0.14
(continued from previous page)
# A The first parameter of the Lennard-Jones potential.
# B The second parameter of the Lennard-Jones potential.
# cutoff
pot = m.Potential.lennard_jones_12_6(0.275 , cutoff, 9.5075e-06 , 6.1545e-03 , 1.0e-3
˓→)
# create a particle type
# all new Particle derived types are automatically
# registered with the universe
class Argon(m.Particle):
mass = 39.4
# bind the potential with the *TYPES* of the particles
m.Universe.bind(pot, Argon, Argon)
# uniform random cube
positions = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=(10000, 3))
for pos in positions:
# calling the particle constructor implicitly adds
# the particle to the universe
Argon(pos)
# run the simulator interactive
m.Simulator.run()

But I don't know how I can install Mechanica. In cmd line I write:
C:\Users\Usuario>pip install mechanica

and get:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mechanica (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mechanica`

How can I install Mechanica? I have Python and pip installed:
C:\Users\Usuario>python3 --version
Python 3.12.4
C:\Users\Usuario>python3 -m pip --version
pip 24.0 from C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.12)

C:\Users\Usuario>python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\program files\windowsapps\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_3.12.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages (24.0)
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-24.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (70.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (0.43.0)
Downloading pip-24.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.8 MB)
   ---------------------------------------- 1.8/1.8 MB 3.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pip
  WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.12.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-24.1


Mechanica is distributed as a compiled binary, and those are version-dependent.  They do not yet have Python 3.12 versions.  You might try installing an older Python.  Note that the current version (0.0.30) appears to be Mac-only.

How can I install an older python? in cmd?

How did you install this one?  Uninstall it and go to https://www.python.org/downloads/
